# $\int_{\gamma}^{}\frac{1}{z}dz$, $\gamma$ is the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=1$ traversed once with the positive orientation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am unable to find the integral $\int_{\gamma}^{}\frac{1}{z}dz$, $\gamma$ is the ellipse $x^2+4y^2=1$ traversed once with the positive orientation. This maybe possible to be done using Cauchy-Goursat but I cannot seem to find anyway whatsoever to solve this. Hope someone could help me out. Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you know and what you don't, but perhaps noting the result is **exactly the same** if instead of that ellipse you integrate over **any** circle centered at the origin and with positive radius: in any case it equals $\;2\pi i\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc If you have an answer you can post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the circle $\;S^1:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|=1\iff z= e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\right\}\;$ , then

$$z=e^{it}\iff dz=ie^{it}dt\implies\oint\limits_{S^1}\frac{dz}{z}=\int\limits_0^{2\pi} i\,dt=2\pi i$$

Since the function in the integral is analytic everywhere except at the origin, it doesn't matter whether we integrate on the given ellipse or in the above circle.

Answer (score 1):

This integral can be viewed as a limiting case of the integrals 
$$I_\epsilon=\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} \frac{1}{z} dz $$ where $\gamma_\epsilon$ is the ellipse after removing an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of the point $(-1,0)$. For such contours you may use the principal branch of the logarithm as a primitive function and obtain

$$I_\epsilon=\log B_\epsilon-\log A_\epsilon \sim \log1+i \pi-(\log 1-i \pi)=2 \pi i. $$
where the $\sim$ means as $\epsilon \to 0$.